# Ways to schedule a class in Salesforce

Tags: schedulebatch

I want to know different ways by which I can schedule a class in salesforce!? I know we can do it using Developer console and SetUp.. But what are other ways by which we can schedule a class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Lightning:
Go to Setup->Custom Code->Apex Class.

So, find your class. It should implements *Schedulable* and then click Schedule Apex.

Thru Developer Console, go here -> [Developer Console](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/80277/sample-code-to-schedule-an-apex-class)

Reference: [Schedule Apex Jobs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_schedule_batch_apex.htm&type=5)

Answer (score 0):

One Way is to schedule from Apex, either Anonymous or Synchronously from other class.

```
schedulableClass m = new schedulableClass();
String sch = '20 30 8 10 2 ?';
String jobID = system.schedule('Merge Job', sch, m);
```

Visit [Details](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm)